# Yii2 How to correctly register a CSS file

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app

I'm trying to register a CSS file in this way

```
$this->registerCssFile('../node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.css', [
    'depends' => [\yii\web\JqueryAsset::className()]
    ]);
```

But I get the error:

> Failed to load a resource.

For instance, I know that I am standing at web folder, so that's why I wrote the above code in that way.

I tried without the `registerCssFile` and I achieved it writing directly this in the view file:

```
<link href="../node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Therefore I think the error is in the `registerCssFile` cause when I inspect in the browser this method add a slash (/) before all the relative path:

```
<link href="/../node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Anyway, THE QUESTION is how can I do to achieve it with `regiserCssFile`(the correct way)?

Or how can I remove that slash?

Just in case:

```
/yii2app
        |_/views
                |_/whatever
                           |_myview.php
        |_/web
        |_/node_modules
                       |_/fullcalendar
                                     |_/dist
                                            |_fullcalendar.css
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The first thing that I would advise you is to move the folder inside the `web` directory and remove the trailing `../` from the URL.

  Like below

  ```
  $this->registerCssFile('node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.css', [
      'depends' => [\yii\web\JqueryAsset::className()]
  ]);
  ```

  The **`/yii2app/web`** directory is where your application [**`Entry script`**](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-entry-scripts.html#entry-scripts) is running from so you do not need to provide a path relative to the view file, but the `web` directory.
- Otherwise, use `AssetManager` to load assets from outside the `web` directory and use the `$sourcePath` option to use the directory outside the `web`.

  see below a demo for Asset manager.

  ```
  namespace app\assets;
  use Yii;
  use yii\web\AssetBundle;
  use yii\web\View;


  // set @themes alias so we do not have to update baseUrl every time we change themes
  Yii::setAlias('@themes', Yii::$app->view->theme->baseUrl);

  /**
   * Main frontend application asset bundle.
   */
  class FullCalendarAsset extends AssetBundle
  {
      public $sourcePath = '@app/node_modules/';

      public $css = [
          'fullcalendar/dist/_fullcalendar.css',       
      ];
      public $js = [


      ];
      public $depends = [
          'yii\web\YiiAsset',
          'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
          'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapPluginAsset',        
      ];

  }
  ```

  place the above file inside the `app/assets` directory and then inside your view

  ```
  use app\assets\FullCalendarAsset;
  FullCalendarAsset::register($this);
  ```

  you should learn about the application [**`LIFE CYCLE`**](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-applications.html#application-lifecycle).

Comment: Thank you Muhammad, I did your first solution and it's working great. Regards.

Comment: you are welcome @MarkWatney :) glad i could help you out